# Template method pattern application

Tags: java, design-patterns, template-method-pattern

I have implemented the template method design pattern to handle the generation of different types of emails in this way:

```
public abstract class TemplateBuilder {
    
     public buildEmail(Map<String,Object> emailObjects) {
            // do something here
     }
}
```

I was forced to pass a dictionary, let's call `emailObjects` like this, because each concrete class that extends `TemplateEmailBuilder` has a different signature of the method `buildEmail`. In this way I can retrieve from the map, the specific objects that I need to build a specific email. Each object I retrieve is an instance of a specific class I use in my code base, useful to create an email.

Is there any way to generalize this and to avoid passing a Map to the template method?

Comment: You can try using `public abstract class TemplateBuilder<T>`, you can use additional interfaces to add features like  `? extends T`

Comment: Thank you @HimadriMandal! Tried this option and got rid of my map